# Gerando um arquivo xlsx a partir de um GridView que e alimentado por um Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

Boa Tarde, estou enfrentando um problema na hora de gerar um arquivo Excel, consegui fazer as informações aparecerem no Excel e serem mostrado na Tela, mas me encontrou com duvida quando tento gerar apenas um arquivo com as informações, minha duvida seria como faço para gerar esse arquivo ou o que tenho que implementar no meu código para que funcione

```
    private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Esse codigo gera um arquivo Excel tirando as informações do Grid.

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        for(int i=0; i < grdRelatorio.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = grdRelatorio.Rows[i];
            for(int j=0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                Excel.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = row.Cells[j].ToString();
            }
        }

        Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\Arquivos Excel");
        Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

        Excel.Quit();

        //Esse codigo passa as informações do Grid para um Excel e abre na Tela.

        /*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible = true;

        for(int i = 1; i < grdRelatorio.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i] = grdRelatorio.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        for(int i=0; i< grdRelatorio.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < grdRelatorio.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = grdRelatorio.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }*/

    }
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida e o erro?

Comment: Desculpa não deixei isso explicito kk, minha duvida e como faço para gerar um arquivo Excel

Comment: Já tentou o método `SaveAs()`, o seu `SaveCopyAs(path)` não deveria ter o caminho completo como no me do arquivo? O seu código retorna algum erro?

Comment: Bem com o SaveAs e o SaveCopyAs o resultado está sendo o mesmo, o programa trava na hora que clico no botão e o arquivo não e gerado

Comment: Como assim trava... você debugou para ver o que acontece?

Comment: Fiz isso com um "professor" ele me disse que não era pra travar por que eu estou apenas lendo os dados do Grid e que pode existir um erro de logica nos meu for. Eu não sei ao certo por que sou iniciante ainda, não sei o melhor jeito para gerar esse arquivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui obter resultado reutilizando o código que gerava uma Janela do Excel com os dados, apenas tive que adicionar 3 linhas que foi a do caminho do arquivo que passei com parâmetros para sempre criar um arquivo novo e salvei os dados na linha seguinte. (:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < grdRelatorio.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i] = grdRelatorio.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        for(int i=0; i< grdRelatorio.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < grdRelatorio.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = grdRelatorio.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(string.Format(@"C:\Arquivos Excel\{0}_{1}.xlsx", lblConexao.Text, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
        Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        Excel.Quit();
```